# RoboEarth.OWL not find

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, roboearth, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How roboearth.owl be useful for robot to infer missing component in a table ?!
I do not know as it does not want to open with me so I do not know its content
[http://www.roboearth.org/kb/roboearth.owl#PickUpBottle',](http://www.roboearth.org/kb/roboearth.owl#PickUpBottle%27,)_

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45830/roboearth.owl-not-find/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The IRI of an OWL identifier does not have to coincide with the file from which the data is loaded, and does not even have to exist. It is intended to be a globally unique identifier.

For example, the RoboEarth namespace http://www.roboearth.org/kb/roboearth.owl# is used for all information downloaded from the RoboEarth knowledge base which is usually not in the roboearth.owl file.

In the tutorial that you have probably followed, you have downloaded the respective OWL file from RoboEarth, it should have been cached in the file re_comm/tmp/serveadrink.serveadrink.owl

Alternatively, you can also manually search the RoboEarth knowledge base after creating an account at http://api.roboearth.org/

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-15**:
Sorry I am not understand your answer

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-10-15**:
KnowRob is a complex system and requires some understanding of the underlying knowledge representation techniques. I'd recommend to start with the 'getting started' tutorial that refers to an OWL tutorial which explains these terms: http://www.ros.org/wiki/knowrob#Tutorials

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-15**:
Ok thanks a lot.